# Concerning the post picture size of facebook page/group feed by Graph Api

Tags: php, html, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I am displaying feed/posts of facebook page/group via graph api in my site by calling this Url in php code -

> https://graph.facebook.com/page_id/feed?access_token=token_value

Then, Among many type of posts, for a post of picture type i get picture url as

> http://photos-g.ak.fbcdn.net/hphotos-ak-frc3/t1.0-0/1972372_10152261154160659_883879121_s.jpg

Now it's the small size as the last part "_s.jpg" indicates.But i want all picture sizes be large.So to achieve this what parameters are needed to include in the graph api url - "https://graph.facebook.com/page_id/feed?access_token=token_value" so that all picture/video type of posts' picture will be in large size??, so is there will be "_b.jpg" at last as i presume.Is that possible in one graph api call?

I searched through the google but no luck, but ended up planning that i would replace the last part of the pic url above with "_b.jpg" so that url will be like -

> http://photos-g.ak.fbcdn.net/hphotos-ak-frc3/t1.0-0/1972372_10152261154160659_883879121_b.jpg

But are there any drawbacks for this hack?? what are the correct ways to achieve if possible in one graph api call.

Answer (score 2):

notice,

```
/page/feed?fields=attachments
```

this will give you all of the attachments in their full sizes. worked charms for me

Answer (score 1):

You could use a FQL query to get the source info of the large versions of the photos use in a Page's feed:

```
SELECT pid, object_id, src_big, src_big_width, src_big_height FROM photo WHERE object_id in (SELECT attachment.media.photo.fbid FROM stream WHERE source_id={page_id} AND actor_id={page_id})
```

Comment: By this query i am getting pic url with last "_n.jpg".It's look like another api call instead what i wanted is all with the first api call as i had 1 more api call which i did not mention.Anyway what about my hack? is it error free?

Comment: Also when i try to apply hack by changing b.jpg to s.jpg for a picture url in video type post, i get no image meaning there is no small size of the video post picture.Likewise, if i try to change as i said from s.jpg to b.jpg in pic url, could there be that image not exists error appear?

Comment: Well, I'd recommend to stick with my suggested solution, because it's not a hack. You can use the Batch API to batch the two neccessary queries of your Use Case into one. I think this would be a much more stable scenario.

Comment: why not this query getting any photo url - `SELECT pid, object_id, src_big FROM photo WHERE object_id in (SELECT attachment.media.photo.fbid FROM stream WHERE source_id=6650304666 AND actor_id=6650304666 limit 200) limit 200` as i need correct photo url of the page/group feed post

Comment: I don't really see a difference to what I suggested other than you just added the Page IDs.

Comment: The id 6650304666 doesn't seem to be a page obejct. Did you check this?

Comment: It's a valid page id you can check by loading.as you said a page id need to be put so not getting why it not a object id.i also tried putting a group id but same prob!.how do i get thing correctly?

Comment: Didn't work this morning, but works now. Strange. The Page apparently doesn't contain photo posts, therefore the subquery result is emtpy. Try a page with photos.

Comment: Yes strange, if you load that page feed in graph api explorer with limit 200 ! you will see some photo posts which not showing up in fql query. Also should not it return photo sizes of link and video posts too as these posts have photo urls you can check in graph api explorer?

Comment: what other alternative ways i can get big pic size only per post??

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if that’s actually documented somewhere – but in Graph API Explorer, the “Search for a field” feature suggests a field called `full_picture`. A few quick tests suggest that for most feed items, it returns the original image that was used making the post, whether it was a picture uploaded with the post, a video thumbnail or whatever.

You can use it in your feed calls like this:

```
/{user-or-page-id}/feed?fields=full_picture,message,type,…
```

Only fields you will get by default when using the `fields` parameter are `id` and `created_time`, everything else you might be interested in (`message`, `type`, `from`, etc.) you will have to ask for specifically as well.

---

That is for any type of feed item that might have a picture attached – expect for `type:photo`. For those, you get an `object_id` as well, and when you query that explicitly in a second request, you get an `images` data structure, that lists the different image sizes Facebook has on their CDN.

I have not found a wya to make it spit out that additional info within the original `/foo/feed` request in one go though – but if you collect all object_id that call delivers, you can use them in a second call like this to get the info for multiple objects at once:

```
/?ids=object_id1,object_id2,…&fields=images
```

Comment: it's look very good by including `fields=full_picture` with graph api, but bit confused about what fields to include for page/group/profile feed properly! in same call. But is it possible to do that(getting full pic sizes for all posts of page/group) by Fql query?? as i already have a 2nd fql query call for other purposes, so i can include another pic size getting query in my 2nd call to save time.many thanks and i am aware of `object_id` only for photo posts but my intention was for any type of posts pictures.

Answer (score 1):

with every feed there is a node name object-Id, use this id like this

graph.facebook.com/object-id/picture?type=large

if it shows question mark photo then use access_token=XXXXXX in query string.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out, but it's only for photo posts. do you think it's illogical/various problems to show big photo sizes in other type of posts like link, video?